# how to change image in Recycler View in android (like a radio button)?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am having Recycler View. It's like a grid view. A total of 9 images in grid layout. If I click a image in any one of the above, that image have to change to an another image. If I click another image. Last one want to reset. Then the clicked image alone will change to highlighted image.
Here is my code...

```
holder.mLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(View view) {

            //for (int i = 0; i < data_collection.size(); i++) {

                holder.mLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.mHighLighted.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if (position == i) {

                }
            //}
            holder.mLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.mHighLighted.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            mHighLight.onHighLight(position, view);
        }
    });
```

Comment: This can be managed by a custom ViewHolder class with a method/methods that allows you to get manage the images within that view.

Comment: Please tell me some example. Am new to android. Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

Remove what you dont need.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final SimpleViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.textView.setText(elements.get(position).getName());
    holder.textView.setTypeface(typeface1);
    CircularImageView circularImageView = (CircularImageView) holder.linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.personazhe_layout_grid_item_image);
    //  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    //    circularImageView.setBackground(elements.get(position).getPhoto());
    //  }
```

circularImageView.setImageDrawable(elements.get(position).getProfileImage());
        //Picasso.with(context).load(elements.get(position).getProfileImage()).into(circularImageView);
        holder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

```
            if(pos != position){


            c.setImageDrawable(elements.get(position).getProfileImage());
            t.setText(elements.get(position).getName());
            seekBar.setProgress(0);
            pos = position;
            }

            //image = elements.get(position).getProfileImage();
            // textviews
          //  trajneri = elements.get(position).getTrajneri();
         //   mosha = elements.get(position).getMosha();
          //  vendbanimi = elements.get(position).getVendbanimi();
          //  vendlindja = elements.get(position).getVendlindja();
          //  arsimi = elements.get(position).getArsimi();
          //  name = elements.get(position).getName();
           // surname = elements.get(position).getSurname();
           // pos = elements.get(position).number();
          //  posi = position;


          //  button.performClick();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ViewHolder pattern is something that Android pushed developers to use for a long time, and then (rightfully) forced on them with RecyclerViews. The idea, opposed to a simple ListView, is that you reuse as much of the view as possible when scrolling to reduce inflation and resource identification. The ViewHolder should be managed as something that is changed/not created within the RecyclerView.

Because of that, storing information in a ViewHolder that must be persistent will not work. For that, there are a plethora of other options. Let's go with an inner class that will manage holding onto the currently selected view position and its relative images.

Let's say we have a custom ViewHolder like below:

```
public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private ImageView iv;

    public ImageViewHolder(View v){
        iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iv);
    }

    public ImageVie getImageView(){
        return iv;
    }
}
```

And utilizing that view holder is an adapter `DemoAdapter`, we can modify it to look something like this:

```
public class DemoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

    public interface SelectionListener{
        void onImageSelected(Bitmap bmp);
    }

    private static class SelectionHolder{
        protected int position;
        protected Bitmap originalBmp, newBmp;

        public SelectionHolder(int position, Bitmap originalBmp,
                Bitmap newBmp){
            this.position = position;
            this.originalBmp = originalBmp;
            this.newBmp = newBmp
        }
    }

    private SelectionHolder selectionHolder;
    private SelectionListener selectionListener;

    /*
     Pre-existing Adapter functionality
     */

    public void setSelectionListener(SelectionListener listener){
        selectionListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        /*
         Pre-existing onBindViewHolder code
         */

        ImageView iv = holder.getImageView();

        if(selectionHolder != null && selectionHolder.position == position)
            iv.setImageBitmap(selectionHolder.newBmp);
        else{
            //set the image however you are doing it now
        }

        iv.setOnClickListener(
                new new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        ImageView iv = (ImageView) v;
                        // Get the IV's current bmp
                        Bitmap originalBmp = getBitmapFromImageView(iv);
                        // Get the currently selected image's "new" image
                        // if it is null, set it to the original bmp
                        // this will initialize our "highlighting"
                        Bitmap newBmp = selectionHolder == null || selectionHolder.newBmp == null?
                            originalBmp: selectoinHolder.newBmp;

                        // set the selection holder
                        selectionHolder = new SelectionHolder(position, originalBmp, newBmp);

                        // notify our listener
                        if(selectionListener != null)
                            selectionListener.onImageSelected(bmp);

                        // refresh the adapter
                        DemoAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmapFromImageView(ImageView iv){
        return ((BitmapDrawable)(iv.getDrawable()).getBitmap()
    }
}
```

Then if we have an activity that needs the selected image, perhaps to display it in an ImageView it hosts

```
recyclerAdapter = new DemoAdapter(...);
recyclerAdapter.setSelectionListener(new SelectionListener(){
    @Override
    public void onImageSelected(Bitmap bmp){
        // set the bmp to your image view or whatever you want
    }
}
```